# Native and SQL Queries in Metabase

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, metabase

My Application's data is stored in both MongoDB and MYSQL. Is there any way to write queries in Metabase that will help in fetching data from both MYSQL and Mongo Databases?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that by "My application's data" you are refering to the data sources, not to the Metabase internal databasa (aka metadata).

As of now (0.32.10), there is no way to query data from two different data sources.
What you can do, though, is to setup two (or more, depending on your need) different questions, and add them to a dashboard - that way, you will be able to show the data in a "data source agnostic" way.

If I didn't not get it wrong, I think this will be somewhat possible in the incoming version (0.33), scheduled for the next weeks (I believe), using the new join system (which will allow you to join data from different data sources, given a certain common key - say, "order_id" or something like that).
You can get more info, and even test the new version (which is currently in the RC2) at
[this link](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/releases/tag/v0.33.0-preview2).